# Workon Command not found when using pi, but works from ssh

Tags: pi-3, ssh, raspbian-stretch, opencv, openssh

when I run the work command to get into my cv virtual environment on my pi it displays

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ workon cv
bash: workon: command not found
```

however when I ssh into my pi from my MacBook and run

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ workon cv
```

it displays

```
(cv)pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I'm quite new to raspberry pi's and I did spill some water on it a few days ago but it seems to be working fine, thanks in advanced for the help

Comment: Apparently the virtual environment setup is not initialised properly. Did you reboot the Pi after installing the virtualenv / virtualenvwrapper modules (which I assume you installed).

Comment: yes and I have tried rebooting it multiple times, however when I run commands in the virtual environment off my MacBook everything seems to work okay until I try to install numpy and it crashes (or just takes very long), both times I have tried to install numpy. which is why I tried to do it directly from my pi, which is then when it wouldn't accept the "workon" command @Dirk

Comment: update it has just after 10 mins installed numpy from my MacBook @Dirk

Comment: Where / how is the initialisation for the virtualenvwrapper done? Did you add it to any of the startup / login script? I have added it to ~./bashrc, which will make sure it's done with every login

Comment: I did it in the ~/.profile I think @Dirk

Comment: Trying to find again which scripts are run with interactive, etc login shells, but cannot find a definitive guide ATM. Can you try to put the init lines in ~/.bashrc and hen try again?

Comment: IIRC .profile is not run on a non-login shell (e.g. terminal in the GUI). SSH uses login shell so .profile is run. This seems to be consistent what you see and so I think using ~/.bashrc should work.

Comment: Thank you, will try and sort that later today! @Dirk

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you put the activation code for virtualenvwrapper in the wrong bash startup script.

`~/.profile` is not run on a non-login shell (like the terminal started in the GUI). It *is* run if you log in using SSH. To have it activated in both situations you can move the code over to `~/.bashrc`

NB: the code you have to move looks something like this. This is what's in my `.bashrc`, but it will be slightly different on your system

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/dev/virtenv
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/dev
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

one method of doing this is by running:

```
source ~/.profile
workon cv
```

Comment: The OP is logged in as user **pi**. On login the script `~/.profile` is executed. What makes it a difference executing it once again?

Comment: I currently don't have the expertise to know the exact reason why, but when I am logged in as user pi, and run workon cv without running source ~/.profile the workon command is not found. It works fine if source ~/.profile is run beforehand. I will look into this and update accordingly.

Comment: That would be an interesting and important information. Maybe the path is broken? Check before and after execution of `~/.profile` with this commands: `which workon` and `echo $PATH`.