# Using Putty and VNC

Tags: ssh, vnc, putty

I have an RPi3B+ which I can connect to through either Putty or VNC, both work fine. I've installed virtualenv with `pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`.

When I'm connected through Putty and I issue the command `workon <envname>` I can enter the virtual environment without issue, but when I do the same having opened up a terminal in VNC, I get `bash: workon: command not found`.

I've issued `pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper` on VNC, and it's definitely there, but still get `command not found`.

Also, python modules that I've imported while connected by VNC aren't available when connected by Putty.

Why the difference? Aren't they just two different ways to access the same machine?

Comment: sounds like you added the activation code in the wrong file. Which file did you add the code to? If it's in ~/.profile you should change that to ~/.bashrc. See comments on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90173/workon-command-not-found-when-using-pi-but-works-from-ssh (as you can see it's not confirmed it's the issue, but I'm fairly sure)

Comment: Yes, I did put it in ~/.profile now that you mention it. I added the lines 

`export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs \
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 \
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

to the file. Do I need to put those into ~/.bashrc too?

Comment: Ah, apparently I do. @Dirk if you change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you put the activation code for virtualenvwrapper in the wrong bash startup script.

`~/.profile` is not run on a non-login shell (like the terminal started in the GUI). It *is* run if you log in using SSH. To have it activated in both situations you can move the code over to `~/.bashrc`

NB: the code you have to move looks something like this. This is what's in my `.bashrc`, but it will be slightly different on your system

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/dev/virtenv
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/dev
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```